# Simple apache mod_rewrite URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Alright, I have a seemingly simple thing that I am trying to do that I would love some help on.

I have a URL like this:

http://www.example.com/api/?q=sometask&paramX=somevalue&paramY=someothervalue

And I would like it to accessed through:

http://www.example.com/api/sometask/?paramX=somevalue&paramY=someothervalue

The "q" value could be as simple as "sometask" or as complex as "sometask/123/otherthing/y" but it will always be the value of "q".  And the rest of the parameters (paramX and paramY, for example) should just be tacked on at the end of the URL.

For example, I would like:

http://www.example.com/api/?q=sometask/123/otherthing/y&paramX=somevalue&paramY=someothervalue&paramZ=somethirdvalue

To be accessible through:

http://www.example.com/api/sometask/123/otherthing/y/?paramX=somevalue&paramY=someothervalue&paramZ=somethirdvalue

I have setup some really really basic mod_rewrite rules in the past (pageA redirects to pageB, etc.), but I'm not really familiar enough with it to even write this (seemingly) simple rule.  So, any help (answer) would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/(.+)/$ /api/?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks; I appreciate the response!  My actual URL is structured like this: http://www.example.com/api/rest2/?q=sometask/123/otherthing/y&paramX=somevalue&paramY=someothervalue&paramZ=somethirdvalue  (the "rest2" is new in the URL).   I thought I would be able to simply take your script and modify it like this: RewriteRule ^api/rest2/(.+)/$ /api/rest2/?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]  but that doesn't seem to be working. It returns a "page cannot be found" error.  Am I modifying it incorrectly to have the "rest2" value in there? Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting just the new url to resolve to the actual one (/api/rest2/sometask/? to /api/rest2/?q=sometask) or the actual url to change to the new one? (/api/rest2/?q=sometask to /api/rest2/sometask/?)

Comment: I think I got it figured out. :)  Instead of putting the rewrite rule into the root directory, I am now putting the following rule directly inside the /api/rest2 directory:  RewriteRule (.+) /api/rest2/test.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]  And this works great.  I was having trouble getting the ^api/rest2/ portion to be recognized, and this gets rid of that trouble.  Your answer was great though; thanks!

Comment: You could have used `RewriteRule ^(api/rest2)/(.+)/$ /$1/test.php?q=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` from outside too. You never mentioned anything about `test.php` before.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! The "test.php" was simply a test redirect location for the new rule as I was playing with it.  In the rule, as I was testing it, I just swapped out ?q=$1 with test.php?q=$1 and it worked just fine.  Now that things are working the way I was hoping they would, I have removed the test.php?q=$1 and replaced it with just ?q=$1. Thanks again!